# combine multiple C# projects

Tags: c#, user-interface

Summary:
Create master application to run other applications by combining code in visual studio.

Details:
I have 3 projects (all c#) that i can open in visual studio. They all work. They are all GUI based applications. I want to create a master application with just a few buttons on it that will open each application if the corresponding button is clicked.

I know that i can accomplish this by "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"program1.exe");" but i don't want to package it all together and have to give my coworkers multiple exe files and hope they read the instructions and execute the right file. I would like to instead take all the .cs files from the applications and import them into my master application. I want program1's files to kick off when i press program1button and have it start as it normally does. Is this possible?

example:
This master application will look like the below description. When program1button is clicked i want to run program1.

```
_____________________
| master application|
|                   |
|  |program1Button| |
|                   |
|  |program2Button| |
|                   |
|  |program3Button| |
|                   |
|___________________|
```

Comment: do they have to be executables? what about MEF and doing the apps as plugins for the "launcher"?

Comment: Whats MEF? im pretty new to visual studio.

Comment: FYI, the language is named "C#", not "C Sharp" or "csharp"

Comment: Much appreciated, you're always helpful Mr.Saunders. EDITED: reread it and it sounded like i was being sarcastic. My apologies for any misconceptions.

Comment: MEF is "Microsoft Extension Framework" its part of the .net 4, and is also available on codeplex.  it's basically a plugin framework for C#

Comment: thanks Muad'Dib. Ill research MEF and see if it works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you want all of the code in one project, and one .exe, you'll need to merge all of the logic into one solution and project file.

Comment: exactly. But do i have to copy paste it all into one .cs? Each application has its own GUI. I really want to open the custom GUI for each one.

Comment: Is this a winforms application? You would simply create other forms, and show/hide the forms depending on the functionality you want to invoke. You should be able to move the actual forms and corresponding files into the unified project, you'll have some work to do on showing/hiding forms, and any data you need to pass between them.

Comment: John, i think that is exactly what i want to do. I have never done that before and have been striking out with google searches trying to find code examples. Do you have any links that could help out?

Comment: I guess I'm kind of confused. If you have a winforms application now, and there's three of them, create a new solution, and bring all the files into it. Your initial application's main form would be what opens the other forms. It's not much harder than saying add new form to the project. I don't know what links I would find to show you... are the other three applications not created by you?

Comment: Oh ok. That is way more simple then i was making it. I wrote all 3 applications. I dont really know how to use visual studio, ive just pieced the codes together through google searching. To more clearly define what i was asking to your original question is "how to do call the other form?"

Comment: So if you're on 'main form' and you have a form called Form1 you'd do something like this: Form1 frm = new Form1(); frm.Show(); Sorry I'm not in front of a VS box right this second, so if my syntax is off, my apologies.

Comment: Thanks for all the help John! you've been great. i can use this as a stepping stone to my solution.

Comment: " 'main form' and you have a form called Form1 you'd do something like this: Form1 frm = new Form1(); frm.Show();" This worked like a charm. I just have a bunch of copy/paste to do. Thanks John!

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy.

1. You can create a new exe project, winform or WPF based on your previous app.
2. You can add each project in your solution and add all three projects as reference to new project.
3. Each of your earlier project will have a start point. That you have to manually do in your new project.

WinForm has start point as Application.Run(new MainForm());

So in your new project you can simply create a new instance of form and launch it.

In WPF, also you have to simply create instance of new window based on selection and show the form

Comment: But won't that create multiple .exe files? He said he didn't want to distribute three.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that you can change your project to library type. And if you want only one exe and no dll then you have to add source of each project as link in your new project.