# Combine projects and run forms from TabPages

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I want to combine several winform applications into 1 master application.  I created a new winform project/solution and added the forms from two of the solutions.  I added TabPages to the first form from which to launch other forms.  I also changed the project Output Type to Library as recommended in [combine multiple C# projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781312/combine-multiple-c-sharp-projects)  I am having difficulty getting the 2nd form (classBuilder) to load when I click the Class Builder tab.

[image: form w/tabpages]

I Googled how to  add a form to a TabPage and most posts had very similar code that I inserted as shown but nothing happens when I click the tab.  As a novice I have no idea if I’m on the right path or placed the subject code in the right place.  Need someone way smarter than me to get me on track.  A few concerns I have are: 1)  Each form has a unique app.config file and if I attempt to rename it the main form doesn’t fill in so I put it back to App.config.  I imported the config file for the 2nd form and renamed it ClassBuild.config and the concern is the 2nd form won’t fill in if and when I get it running with some expert help. 2) I don’t understand why I would issue ‘Form frmClassBuilder = new Form();’ when a form by that name already exists.  Is this code okay?

```
namespace VX130
{
    public partial class VX130UI : Form
    {
        public DataTable tblPKIEN;
        public DataTable tblsAttributes;
        public DataTable tbltAttributes;
        public DataSet   dsVX130;

         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        public VX130UI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            //attempt to add form to a tabpage
            Form frmClassBuilder = new Form();
            frmClassBuilder.TopLevel = false;
            tabPage9.Controls.Add(frmClassBuilder);
            frmClassBuilder.Parent = this;
            frmClassBuilder.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            frmClassBuilder.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            frmClassBuilder.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            frmClassBuilder.Show();
            //end attempt

            // tabControl1
        // 
        this.tabControl1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage8);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage9);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage10);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage11);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage12);
        this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 65);
        this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(963, 445);
        this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 2;

        // tabPage9
        // 
        this.tabPage9.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.tabPage9.Name = "tabPage9";
        this.tabPage9.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage9.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(955, 419);
        this.tabPage9.TabIndex = 3;
        this.tabPage9.Text = "Class Builder";
        this.tabPage9.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.tabPage9.Controls.Add(ClassBuilderUI.frmClassBuilder());    is a ‘type’ and not valid in given context
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the TabPage, not the form.  And don't set things like Parent and WindowState for the form you are adding:

```
//Form frmClassBuilder = new Form();
ClassBuilderUI.frmClassBuilder frmClassBuilder = new ClassBuilderUI.frmClassBuilder(); <== to reference existing form (exists in solution
frmClassBuilder.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
frmClassBuilder.TopLevel = false;
frmClassBuilder.Visible = true;
tabPage9.Controls.Add(frmClassBuilder);
tabPage9.Show();
```

> I don’t understand why I would issue ‘Form frmClassBuilder = new
>   Form();’ when a form by that name already exists.

Exists where? How?  You need an instance of the form to add to the Tab page control collection.  If you already had an instance, you could add it.  Just be sure it doesn't get `Close()` or `Dispose()` called on it.

The code in your `ClassBuilderTab_MouseClick` handler looks useless.  I would remove that unless you have some other need for it.

Comment: Exists where?  Imported into solution by add existing item.  If I change Application.Run(new VX130.VX130UI()); to Application.Run(new ClassBuilderUI.frmClassBuilder()); it displays.

Comment: That is irrelevant.  In that example, you'd be creating an instance of the form as the form to be displayed when running the application.  But what you want is for the new combined form to show, and then display the others within it.  Therefore, you need instances of the others, and that is what my answer shows how to do.

Comment: Sorry got timed out.

Thank you.  Yes, ClassBuilderTab_MouseClick was useless. Removed.

With replacement code you suggested a form outline is now being drawn when tab is clicked.  It's totally blank except an Icon in upper left corner.

"Exists where?"  Imported into solution by add existing item.  If I change Application.Run(new VX130.VX130UI()); to Application.Run(new ClassBuilderUI.frmClassBuilder()); it displays.

"You need an instance of the form to add to the Tab page control collection."  I don't know how to do this.  I tried as shown in appended code but isn't correct.

Comment: Don't know if you saw my comment where the form is not displaying when tab is clicked.  Only the outline and an Icon in upper left corner.  Is there something missing?

Comment: If you could add the line from my answer to yours to make your answer complete, I'll check yours as the answer since you provided a key piece of showing the tabpage.
ClassBuilderUI.frmClassBuilder frmClassBuilder = new ClassBuilderUI.frmClassBuilder(); <== to reference existing form (exists in solution

Answer (score 0):

I found what was missing piece to create instance of an existing form (exists in solution).

```
    public VX130UI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        ClassBuilderUI.frmClassBuilder frmClassBuilder = new ClassBuilderUI.frmClassBuilder(); <== to reference existing form (exists in solution
        //Form frmClassBuilder = new Form();
        frmClassBuilder.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frmClassBuilder.TopLevel = false;
        frmClassBuilder.Visible = true;
        tabPage9.Controls.Add(frmClassBuilder);
        tabPage9.Show();
```